# Isolinux PCMCIA USB 3.0 Bootloader

Tags: bootloader, isolinux

My laptop doesn't have USB 3.0. So I installed a USB 3.0 PCMCIA expansion card. But I can't boot directly from it! I can access it via Ubuntu. Now I want to create a Boot CD/USB stick with ISOLINUX that has support for the PCMCIA card, so I can boot to a connected USB 3.0 stick! But when I try to boot the self made bootloader ISO, it always says "Failed to load ldlinux.c32"

I'm following two tutorials but I get the same error.
https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/boot-cd-mit-isolinux-initrd-img-ergaenzen-um-/
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch

What am I doing wrong? My system is an older 32 bit laptop.

**UPDATE:** I tried it with Grub's eltorito instead of isolinux.bin and at least it it loads the initrd.lz! I can even find my USB 3.0 stick in the expansion card with ls -la /dev/disk/by-id. But I can't boot from it when I give the root=/dev/sd.. argument.

Comment: Please give more details about what you're trying to do. And what does the bootloader have to do with PCMCIA?

Comment: What are the *exact* Grub commands you're trying to use to boot? What happens when you issue them? Are there any error messages? Please include them *in verbatim* in your question if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out a new, clean Linux installation on stick both bootloader work. Funny thing is, other boot stick boots up without bootloader absolutely normally.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I would strongly recommend not booting through an expansion card. But if you do, always try and use the identifier used for the original port to boot from. Also, make sure that you're not just extracting the iso and copying it to a USB, but actually *mounting* it to the USB. This includes formatting the USB and mounting an ISO file to it. I would recommend just using Rufus for windows to mount an ISO file to a USB as a bootable device. If you're running Ubuntu or Macintosh, use dd. The syntax would go like so:
First you will need to find the path of your USB by running this first *without* the USB inserted in your computer.

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

And then run it again after you insert the USB and see which path appeared that is different from before. An example would be /dev/sdb1. After that you would run the following command to mount the ISO file to the USB.

```
dd if=*your iso file*.iso of=*path to usb* bs=512k
```

Once dd has finished imaging the drive, it will output something that looks like this:

```
5823+1 records in
5823+1 records out
3053371392 bytes (3.1 GB) copied, 746.211 s, 4.1 MB/s
```

After properly mounting the ISO to the USB, try again and update or resolve this question based on your results.

Comment: Hi, It would be better to include the whole answer rather than just "google it". it would be much more beneficial and convenient for anyone who sees the answer to be able to know what you mean rather than having to search for it themselves. I would suggest you edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your feedback, I'll edit that in.